# Redirect user to Dashboard if already authenticated in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Hi i  have a `simple` project ,in this project i have total `three files`, one is `App.js` in the `App.js` i have all the defined `routes` .The second File is `Dashboard.js` ,This is like a secret Page ,This page can only see  `authenticated users`. And this third file is `Protected Route` file. In this file i have defined a Protected Route. Now My question is if `user` is authenticated and  if the he/she  tries to change the `url` to `Home Page`  he should be redirected to `Dashboard.js`

//App.js

```
  import React, { useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Nav from "./Nav";

function App() {
  const [isAuth, setAuth] = useState(false);
  return (
    <Router>
      <Nav />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/">
          <button onClick={() => setAuth(true)}>Login</button>
          <button onClick={() => setAuth(false)}>Logout</button>
        </Route>

        <ProtectedRoute
          exact
          path="/dashboard"
          component={Dashboard}
          isAuth={isAuth}
        />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

//protected route

```
import React from "react";
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
function ProtectedRoute({ isAuth, component: Component, ...rest }) {
  console.log(rest);
  return (
    <div>
      <Route
        {...rest}
        render={(props) => {
          if (isAuth) {
            return <Component />;
          } else {
            return (
              <Redirect
                to={{ pathname: "/", state: { from: props.location } }}
              />
            );
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

//dashboard.js

```
import React from "react";

const Dashboard = (props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dashboard</h1>
      <p>Secret Page</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Comment: what is behaviour right now? do you have any errors in console? Where is your question?

Comment: similar to `ProtectedRoute` you can have a `PublicRoute` component which in you can check in `useEffect` that if `isAuth` is `true` just redirect to `/dashboard`

Comment: Raman Nikitsenka :if user is `logged` in if he tries to type `home page`  in `url` he is redirect to `home page` .But i dont want that behavior.I want if logged in ``redirect` to `dashboad.js`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add Redirect like `ProtectedRoute`:

```
<Route exact path="/">
  {isAuth && <Redirect to={{ pathname: "/dashoard ", state: { from: props.location } }} />}
  <button onClick={() => setAuth(true)}>Login</button>
  <button onClick={() => setAuth(false)}>Logout</button>
</Route>
```

Comment: Yeah it works but small mistake int the `Redirect pathname` it should be `/dashoard`